Given two Json list how to remove the fields in JSon which are null and not present in the Json list named parsedXmlChild and store it in a new list?
parsedJsonChildData (original data): [{date=null, feeForPerformance=null, feeFrequency=5}, {date=12-25-2024, feeForPerformance=23, feeFrequency=1}, {date=12-03-2025, feeForPerformance=1, feeFrequency=5}]

parsedXmlChildData (original data): [{date=null, feeFrequency=5}, {date=12-25-2024, feeForPerformance=23, feeFrequency=1}, {date=12-03-2025, feeForPerformance=1, feeFrequency=5}]

In the first index of parsedJsonChildData, feeForPerformance=null should be removed since it is not available in the parsedXmlChildData , the criterios is if the field is Null in parsedJsonChildData  and not present in parsedXmlChildData it should be removed from parsedJsonChildData
I have tried to make a code but I am still getting the same output
public static List<Map<String, Object>> cleanJsonData(List<Map<String, Object>> parsedJsonChildData, List<Map<String, Object>> parsedXmlChildData) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> modifiedParsedJsonChildData = new ArrayList<>();

    // Iterate over each index in the JSON and XML lists
    for (int i = 0; i < parsedJsonChildData.size(); i++) {
        Map<String, Object> jsonObject = parsedJsonChildData.get(i);
        Map<String, Object> xmlObject = parsedXmlChildData.get(i);

        // Create a new map to hold the cleaned JSON object
        Map<String, Object> cleanedJsonObject = new HashMap<>(jsonObject);

        // Iterate over the entries in the JSON object
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> iterator = cleanedJsonObject.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = iterator.next();
            String jsonField = entry.getKey();
            Object jsonValue = entry.getValue();

            // If the field is null in JSON and is missing in XML, remove it from JSON
            if (jsonValue == null && !xmlObject.containsKey(jsonField)) {
                iterator.remove(); // Remove the field from the copied JSON
                System.out.println("Removed field from JSON: " + jsonField); // Log the removal
            }
        }

        // Add the cleaned JSON object to the modified list
        modifiedParsedJsonChildData.add(cleanedJsonObject);
    }

    return modifiedParsedJsonChildData; // Return the cleaned JSON data only
}

ouptut :
modifiedParsedJsonChildData (after cleaning): [{date=null, feeForPerformance=null, feeFrequency=5}, {date=12-25-2024, feeForPerformance=23, feeFrequency=1}, {date=12-03-2025, feeForPerformance=1, feeFrequency=5}] 

It is still the same

I don't see any XML here, the question refers to XML but it all appears to be JSON.

So basically I had the XML data which I parsed in to this
parsedXmlChildData (original data): [{date=null, feeFrequency=5}, {date=12-25-2024, feeForPerformance=23, feeFrequency=1}, {date=12-03-2025, feeForPerformance=1, feeFrequency=5}]

The fact that the data was at one time in XML format doesn't make this a question about XML. I shall remove the "xml" tag from your question.

I was able to figure out a woking solution
public static List<Map<String, Object>> cleanJsonData(List<Map<String, Object>> parsedJsonChildData, List<Map<String, Object>> parsedXmlChildData) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> modifiedParsedJsonChildData = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < parsedJsonChildData.size(); i++) {
            Map<String, Object> jsonItem = parsedJsonChildData.get(i);
            Map<String, Object> xmlItem = parsedXmlChildData.get(i);

            Map<String, Object> filteredItem = new HashMap<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : jsonItem.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Object value = entry.getValue();


                if ((value != null && !value.toString().isEmpty()) || xmlItem.containsKey(key)) {
                    filteredItem.put(key, value);
                }
            }
            modifiedParsedJsonChildData.add(filteredItem);
        }

        return modifiedParsedJsonChildData;


    }


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
